# How to initialize an object and override a method in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, overriding

Like Other Language, We can create a object and override a method in the object during `initialization`. Please help me How can i do?

**For Example:**

```
    public class DemoInitAndOverride {

    public void handleMessage(){}

}
```

**And in another class**

```
    public class SampleClass {

    public void doSomeThing(){
        DemoInitAndOverride demo = new DemoInitAndOverride(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.handleMessage();
            }
        };
    }

}
****EDIT:****
```

Thanks everyone for possible solutions and suggestion. I think now it is important for me provide some details about the requirement which could help you in providing the solution.

The handler concept is some thing similar to the Android Framework where handlers are used to pass messages between 2 threads or 2 methods. Please see the code demonstration below:

UI Class (Here the user clicks a button, a request is dispatched to the processor class using handler)

**This is the demo handler**

```
/**
 * 
 * Used for thread to thread communication.
 * Used for non UI to UI Thread communication.
 *
 */
public class DemoHandler {

    public void handleMessage(Messages message){}

    final public void sendMessage(final Messages message){
        //Calling thread is platform dependent and shall change based on the platform
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    handleMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**This is simple message class**

```
public class Messages {
    public Object myObject;

    //other hash map (key, values) and get data put data etc
}
```

**This is simple user interface class demo code:**

```
public class UIClass {

    public UIClass(){
        //INIT
    }
    void onClick(int id){
        //Some Button is clicked:
        //if id == sendParcel
        //do
        TransactionProcessor.getInstance().sendParcel(handler, "Objects");
    }

    DemoHandler handler = new DemoHandler(){
        public void handleMessage(Messages message) {
            //Inform the UI and Perform UI changes
            //data is present in the messages
        };
    };
}
```

**This is sample transaction processor class**

public class TransactionProcessor {

```
public static TransactionProcessor getInstance(){
    return new TransactionProcessor(); //for demonstration
}
//Various Transaction Methods which requires calling server using HTTP and process there responses:
public void sendParcel(final DemoHandler uiHander, String otherdetailsForParcel){
    //INIT Code and logical code
    //Logical Variables and URL generation
    String computedURL = "abc.com/?blah";
    DemoHandler serverConnectionHandler = new DemoHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Messages message) {
            super.handleMessage(message);
            //Process server response:
            //create a new message for the UI thread and dispatch
            Messages response = new Messages();
            //add details to messages
            //dispatch
            uiHander.sendMessage(response );
        }
    };
    new Thread(new ServerConnection(computedURL, serverConnectionHandler));
}
public void sendEmail(final DemoHandler uiHander, String otherdetailsForEmail){
    //SAME AS SEND PARCEL WITH DIFFERENT URL CREATION AND RESPONSE VALIDATIONS
}
public void sendNotification(final DemoHandler uiHander, String otherdetailsForNotifications){
    //SAME AS SEND PARCEL WITH DIFFERENT URL CREATION AND RESPONSE VALIDATIONS
}
```

}

Comment: Removing the `[Java]` as the answer won't have anything to do with Java.

Comment: Thanks, its true ; the answer will have nothing to do with java

Comment: In objective-C whenever you subclass it is overridden automatically, if you want to call super class' method you need to call [super method];

Comment: You can't override a specific method in Objective-C without making a subclass. Take a look at delegates though, I think they'd give you waht you're looking for.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it. Objective-C has its own ways. You may want a category or an extension but that depends on what you want to do with it. In Objective-C I only know stubs for unit testing. Is it that what you want?

Comment: So is your question basically what's the Objective-C equivalent of nested classes in Java? (Or are they called anonymous classes? I think my terminology is imprecise, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to do in Objective-C, but this should work.  It replaces the `doSomething` method of `DemoInitAndOverride` with its own implementation and returns a new instance of the class.  Note however that once this has been done the new implementation remains in place for **all** new instances of the class, not just a single instance.

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"self doSomething called");
}

- (DemoInitAndOverride *)createObj
{
    DemoInitAndOverride *obj = [[DemoInitAndOverride alloc] init];

    SEL sel = @selector(doSomething);
    Method theirMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([DemoInitAndOverride class], sel);
    Method myMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], sel);
    theirMethod->method_imp = myMethod->method_imp;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, the instance complete changes will have issues with my implementation as I am using multiple initiation of the object and method and various places. I have provided more details in the demo code; if you could go through and suggest some way to solve it, it will be great

Answer (score 0):

This is a nasty one, and I recommend creating a subclass or something else.

Here's your answer, which is essentially the same, but at runtime. Proceed at your own risk:

Import this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

And add this code to wherever:

```
- (void)methodName {
    // whatever you want to do in there
}
```

And in your function:

```
Class subclass;
// Verifiy that you haven't created it already
subclass = objc_getClass("SampleClassSubclass");
if (!subclass) {
    // Generate a new class, which will be subclass of your SampleClass
    subclass = objc_allocateClassPair(subclass, "SampleClassSubclass", 0);
    // Obtain the implementation of the method you want to overwrite
    IMP methodImplementation = [self methodForSelector:@selector(methodName)];
    // With that implementation, replace the method
    class_replaceMethod(subclass, @selector(methodName), methodImplementation, "@@:");
    // Register the class you just generated
    objc_registerClassPair(subclass);
}

SampleClass *obj = [[subclass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks @Ismael . I have made changes to the demo code. If you could go through it and suggest me some equivalent implementation or approach it will be great. Instance change for the complete class will make my implementation a failure.